# How to sort a $group aggregate output with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

I am looking sort a collection of documents (emails) by the id of the sender, and then return the sender id's with the most frequent sends, limited to 5.  I'm fairly close but struggling with the syntax now that I need to sort the group.  I understand that with mongodb the `$group` operator does not sort the output, how can I sort the output now once it has been grouped.  I've tried tacking on `.sort()` to the end of the query sequence, as well as setting the output equal to a variable and calling `.sort().limit()` on that to no avail.

I have as follows

```
cursor = db.emailcol.aggregate( 

    [{ $group : {_id : {emails_sent: "$sender_id"}, number : { $sum : 1} }},
        {$sort : {"_id.sender_id": 1}}

    ]
);

while ( cursor.hasNext() ) {
    printjson( cursor.next() );
};
```

which returns:

```
{ "_id" : { "emails_sent" : "6" }, "number" : 3 }
{ "_id" : { "emails_sent" : "5" }, "number" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "emails_sent" : "3" }, "number" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "emails_sent" : "4" }, "number" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "emails_sent" : "2" }, "number" : 1 }
```

How can I either run a sort method on the output of the grouping, or just add the sort and limit to the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sort phase of your aggregation pipeline should be:

```js
{$sort : {"_id.emails_sent": 1}}
```

rather than:

```js
{$sort : {"_id.sender_id": 1}}
```

as the output of the $group phase does not have a sub-document with field `sender_id`.  To debug such issues, it would help to see the output of every phase of the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks so much, I am new to mongodb.  That worked like a charm.  To limit should I just be able to add .limit() to the end of the query?  Instead I keep receiving the response "object has no method limit".

Comment: You can add a $limit phase to the aggregation pipeline right after the $sort phase like: {$limit:1}

Comment: thank you!  I actually pieced that together myself and meant to come back and share - works perfectly.